# watchSession.sendMessage works fine on simulator, times out IRL

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wcsession

I wrote two applications, first using `transferUserInfo`, which caused too much lag (I believe because it sends stuff in background). I switched to `sendMessage` and was very happy with the results (faster response time). When attempted to run the application on my real iPhone and Apple Watch, I received `Transfer timed out.` Here's the full code and example of one of the debugs:

iPhone:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchManager: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

    var counter = 0

    var watchSession: WCSession? {
        didSet {
            if let session = watchSession {
                session.delegate = self
                session.activate()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        watchSession = WCSession.default

    }


    private func sendDict(_ dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.watchSession?.sendMessage(dict, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: {error in print(error.localizedDescription)})
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var transferButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func dataTransfer(_ sender: Any) {
        sendDict(["DataKey": counter])
        counter+=1
        print("sent")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        print("Session activation did complete")
    }

    public func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("session did become inactive")
    }

    public func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("session did deactivate")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        print("phone received app context: ", message)
        if let temperature = message["DataKey"] as? String {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.transferButton.setTitle(temperature, for: .normal)
                self.label.text=temperature
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Apple Watch:

```
//  InterfaceController.swift

import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    var watchSession: WCSession? {
        didSet {
            if let session = watchSession {
                session.delegate = self
                session.activate()
            }
        }
    }


    @IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: WKInterfaceButton!

    private func sendDict(_ dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.watchSession?.sendMessage(dict, replyHandler: nil, errorHandler: {error in print(error.localizedDescription)})
    }

    @IBAction func button() {
        let urg = ["DataKey":UUID().uuidString]
        sendDict(urg)
        print("watch sent app context \(urg)")
    }

}

extension InterfaceController: WCSessionDelegate {

    #if os(iOS)
    public func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) { }
    public func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        session.activate()
    }
    #endif

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        print("Session activation did complete")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
        print("watch received app context: ", message)
        if let temperature = message["DataKey"] as? Int {
            self.temperatureLabel.setTitle(String(temperature))
        }

    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()

        watchSession = WCSession.default

    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Debug Example:

```
Session activation did complete
watch sent app context ["DataKey": "AF793FC6-7A16-4D7D-9A3B-D3BB960EC9D9"]
2019-01-13 21:07:43.524717-0800 testApp WatchKit Extension[1240:1178401] [WC] -[WCSession onqueue_handleMessageCompletionWithError:withMessageID:] C385FF5F-5EA1-478B-A930-54066C2F0B0F due to WCErrorCodeTransferTimedOut -> IDSErrorTypeTimedOut -> IDSResponseTimedOut
2019-01-13 21:07:43.525001-0800 testApp WatchKit Extension[1240:1178401] [WC] -[WCSession _onqueue_notifyOfMessageError:messageID:withErrorHandler:] C385FF5F-5EA1-478B-A930-54066C2F0B0F errorHandler: YES with WCErrorCodeTransferTimedOut -> IDSErrorTypeTimedOut -> IDSResponseTimedOut
Transfer timed out.
```